# How can I correctly call the created type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, frontend, next-auth

I created a type so I could use it wherever I want without having to call useSession(), because it would need to be a client component. But when I call it it always comes undefined (if I call a specific attribute) or an empty object (if I call it all)

created type:

```
"use client"
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"


interface UserType {
  name: string,
  email: string,
  imageProfile: string,
}

const getUser = (): UserType => {
  const { data: session } = useSession()
  if (session) {
    return {
      name: session.user["name"],
      email: session.user["email"],
      imageProfile: session.user["jpegPhoto"]
    }
  }
  return null
};


export { getUser }
```

Where am I calling:

```
import { getUser } from "../../../@types/UserType";
import { ClientImage } from "../../../components/ClientImage";
import DevComponent from "../../../components/DevComponents";

export default function Profile() {
  const user = getUser
  console.log("usuario:", user)
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Profile Page</h1>
      <ClientImage />
      <DevComponent />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Thank you in advance for your attention!!

what did I try:
calling:

```
  const user = getUser()
  console.log("usuario:", user.name)

  const user = getUser
  console.log("usuario:", user)
```

creating the component:

```
"use client"
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"


interface UserType {
  name: string,
  email: string,
  imageProfile: string,
}

const getUser = ({name,email, imageProfile}: UserType) => {
  const { data: session } = useSession()
  if (session) {
    return {
      name: session?.user["name"],
      email: session?.user["email"],
      imageProfile: session?.user["jpegPhoto"]
    }
  }
  return null
};


export { getUser }
```

What am I waiting for you to return:

```
user{
name: "sam",
email: "sam@domin.com,
imagePhoto: "<the photo in base64>"
}
```

**New error after changes to the first answer**

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Source
src/types/UserType.ts (11:38) @ useSession

   9 |
  10 | function getUser(): UserType | null {
> 11 | const { data: session } = useSession()
     |                                    ^
  12 | if (session) {
  13 |   return {
  14 |     name: session?.user["name"] || '',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Profile` component, you are not calling the `getUser` function. You are just assigning the function itself to the `user` variable. Update it to call the function like this:

```
import { getUser } from "../../../@types/UserType";
import { ClientImage } from "../../../components/ClientImage";
import DevComponent from "../../../components/DevComponents";

export default function Profile() {
  const user = getUser(); // Call the function
  console.log("usuario:", user);
  
  if (user) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Profile Page</h1>
        <p>Name: {user.name}</p>
        <p>Email: {user.email}</p>
        <p>Image Profile: {user.imageProfile}</p>
        <ClientImage />
        <DevComponent />
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return <p>Loading...</p>; // Handle the case when user is not available yet
  }
}
```

In your `getUser` function, you are trying to destructure the properties from the `UserType` interface, but the function does not take any arguments. Instead, you should remove the parameter from the function and directly return the user object:

```
"use client"
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";

interface UserType {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  imageProfile: string;
}

const getUser = (): UserType | null => {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  if (session) {
    return {
      name: session.user?.name || "",
      email: session.user?.email || "",
      imageProfile: session.user?.jpegPhoto || ""
    };
  }
  return null;
};

export { getUser };
```

Make sure you handle cases where the properties might be `undefined` by using the nullish coalescing operator (`||`) or optional chaining (`?.`).

With these changes, you should be able to get the user object and display the information in your `Profile` component.

> For New Error!

It appears that you're facing an error called "Invalid hook call". This error usually occurs when attempting to use a React hook (`useSession` in this case) either outside of a functional component or in a context where hooks are not allowed.

To fix this issue,

**UserType.ts:**

```
// UserType.ts
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";

interface UserType {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  imageProfile: string;
}

const getUser = (): UserType | null => {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  if (session) {
    return {
      name: session.user?.name || "",
      email: session.user?.email || "",
      imageProfile: session.user?.jpegPhoto || ""
    };
  }
  return null;
};

export { getUser };
```

**Profile.tsx:**

```
// Profile.tsx
import { ClientImage } from "../../../components/ClientImage";
import DevComponent from "../../../components/DevComponents";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { getUser } from "../../../@types/UserType";

export default function Profile() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  const user = getUser(session);

  if (user) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Profile Page</h1>
        <p>Name: {user.name}</p>
        <p>Email: {user.email}</p>
        <p>Image Profile: {user.imageProfile}</p>
        <ClientImage />
        <DevComponent />
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }
}
```

To fix this error, I've moved the `useSession` hook inside the `Profile.tsx` component, where it's allowed, and passed the session data to the `getUser` function. This ensures that you follow the rules of React hooks and should resolve the "Invalid hook call" error.

Comment: When I put "()" it gives this error:
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: (0 , _types_UserType__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.getUser) is not a function

Source
src/app/private/profile/page.tsx (6:22) @ getUser

  4 |
  5 | export default function Profile() {
> 6 | const user = getUser()
    |                    ^
  7 | console.log("usuario:", user)
  8 | return (
  9 |   <div>

I can't add name: session.user?.name || '',

because "jpegPhoto" was created by me so that it collects what the JWT comes from, it has to be imageProfile: session?.user["jpegPhoto"]

Comment: Try updating your import statement :


```jsx
// Update the import statement to include braces for the default import
import { getUser } from "../../../@types/UserType";

// ... rest of the code remains the same

```

Comment: If that doesn't resolve the issue, make sure that the `getUser` function is correctly exported in your `UserType` file.

Comment: What else I did: I changed the variable names, removed the "{}" from the import and nothing works, if I remove the "()" from the useSessio it doesn't have the last error but the values ​​remain undefined

Comment: look at the answer I gave. In the comment, there is a character limitation so I can't give big statements.

Comment: please look at the last change I made to the question

Comment: Please look at the answer again.

Comment: Ok, this really solves the problem, but it creates two others I- it only works when I import it into a client component, II - it gives this error called: Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: I'm glad the initial issue was resolved.

Comment: If you are experiencing issues when using the `useSession` hook in a server-side (Node.js) component, it may be because this hook is intended for use only in client-side (browser) code. To avoid these issues, you can conditionally import the hook and use it only in client-side code. To do this, you can check if the `window` object is defined, which indicates that the code is running in a browser environment, before importing and using the `useSession` hook.

Comment: Please keep in mind the following message: 

"Unhandled Runtime Error - TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node':**"

This error is likely not caused by the modifications you made to the code. It seems like there may be an issue in another part of your code or components.

To identify where the error is being thrown, please check the stack trace in your browser's developer tools. Look for the component or function that triggers the error and review that part of the code for any issues.

Comment: ok I'll read more about it so I can make the code better, thanks for your help and sorry for asking so many questions without explaining them well, I'm new to stackoverflow